# General term for wheat, barley, oat, rye

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

What would you call the thing on the image?
[image]

I am looking for the general term, I know that it has more types:

- wheat
- barley
- oat
- rye

suggestions: plantes céréalières

Comment: The usual term is [*céréales*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9r%C3%A9ale). The specific one on your picture is *blé*.

Answer (score 6):

I would say *céréales*. It is common to call wheat or rice "céréales", as much for the plant as for the cereal itself.